# Склонение имен существительных

Tags: склонение

Склоняются ли наименование городов? Например Астана, Алматы, Алма-Ата

Answer (score 4):

Астана,  Алма-Ата склоняются,Алматы  нет, хотя раньше склонялось.Многие заимствованные географические названия, освоенные русским языком, склоняются по типу существительных женского рода на -а, например:  в Бухаре,  до Анкары, в Астане, в Алма-Ате.

•   не склоняются французские по происхождению топонимы, оканчивающиеся на -а в языке-источнике:Гра, Спа, Ле-Дора, Юра и т.п. Однако названия, к которым в русском языке было прибавлено окончание -а, склоняются: Тулуза, Женева, Лозанна — в Тулузе, Женеве, Лозанне (ср.: Toulouse, Genève, Lausanne);

•   склоняются японские географические названия, оканчивающиеся на -а безударное: Осака — в Осаке, Фукусима — из Фукусимы;

•   не склоняются эстонские и финские наименования: из Ювяскюля, на Сааремаа;

•   испытывают колебания при склонении абхазские и грузинские топонимы, оканчивающиеся на безударное -а. Тем не менее многие из подобных названий склоняются: Очамчира — в Очамчире, Гудаута — до Гудауты, Пицунда — из Пицунды;

•   не склоняются сложные географические названия на -а безударное, заимствованные из испанского и других романских языков: в Баия-Бланка, в Баия-Лaypa, из Херес-¬де-ла-Фронтера, в Сантьяго-де-Куба, от Пола-де-Лена, из Сантьяго-де-Компостела;

•   склоняются сложные славянские названия, являющиеся существительными при наличии словообразовательных признаков прилагательных, например: Бяла-Подляска — из Бяла-Подляски, Банска-Бистрица — до Банска-Бистрицы.
Название «Алматы» переводится как "Яблоневый", в казахском яз. не склоняется, не стало склоняться и в русском по их примеру и требованию, хотя в русском иностранные топонимы на -ы часто склоняются, не склоняются только со словом "город"
Здесь подробно:

http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=bc1c9e6e-c0b5-4df1-8760-b03ea114851b

Answer (score 1):

Алматы не склонялось, да и в русском языке никто Алма-Ату и не отменял. С этим даже казахи уже согласились.
Про Костанай еще спорят.
Причем сугубо между собой.

Comment: Да и Салоглы тоже не склонялось (Азербайджан).

Comment: Не надо про казахов. Вообще не надо про то, о чем не в курсе. 
Алма-ату, увы, отменили. А обратной "отмены отмены" еще не было. И вряд ли будет.  
Казахам вообще еще меньше дела до стенаний русских чем даже белоруссам.

Comment: @behemothus, никто Алма-Ату не отменял. [Сайт посольства РФ в республике Казахстан](http://www.rfembassy.kz/tm/russian_mission_in_kazakhstan/konsulskie_uchrezhdenija/)

Comment: Ага. Грот Вам не указ - а сайт посольства, типа, аргумент.
Да Вам-то ладно, а вот как с казахами быть? Посмотрите хотя бы в Вики.

Comment: @behemothus,я гражданин РФ, и международную политику определяет в нашей стране Президент и МИД, никто другой "отменить" название иностранного города не вправе (в Вики есть ссылка на указ Президентский указ о наименованиях). Институт русского языка даёт рекомендации из узуса, где "Алма-Ата" естественно существует.

Казахстанский диалект русского языка меня интересует мало, и ни каким аргументом за пределами республики Казахстан законы этой страны являться не могут.

Comment: @behemothus, не отсутствии правил, а отсутствии единых для всех правил. Диалектная орфография до 1956 года была вполне допустимой, поэтому для того, чтобы сказать верно или нет написано то или иное слово, нужно знать когда и где оно было написано. Хотя, как я заметил, вам больше нравиться опровергать свое представление о мнении оппонента, чем высказывание его самого, поэтому и доказывать вам что-либо считаю излишним

Comment: Я удалил предыдущий комментарий. Дабы ответить на вот это.  
  
>Хотя, как я заметил, вам больше нравиться опровергать свое представление о мнении оппонента, чем высказывание его самого, поэтому и доказывать вам что-либо считаю излишним    
  
К сожалению, наше чувство более чем взаимно. Поэтому предлагаю в очередной раз сначала хотя бы формулировать тезис о том, что Вы собственно собираетесь опровергать, а потом уже заниматься собственно опровержениями.  

Отвечать Вам буду скорее всего с другого акка. Ибо этот скоро забанят к Вашему и grumant'a вящему удовольствию.

Answer (score 1):

Алма-ата, Астана склоняются, Алматы могло склоняться только в языке XIX века.

Согласна, не надо языковой политики. На Украине уже наелись по уши...

Объясните лучше, как бороться с этим редактором. Устала уже...

Answer (score 0):

Сколько помню, Алмааты никогда не склонялся (после того как перестал быть  Алма-атой). Насчет финских и эстонских названий - это какая-то самодеятельность. Непонятно, кем и почему это правило писано. Я еще могу понять несклонение по фонетическим причинам в отношении названий, заканчивающихся на двойную гласную (на самом деле - там просто долгая),  Но почему не склоняется та же Ювяскюля? А если так, то почему из этого списка исключены карельские названия, звучащие абсолютно как финские?

Comment: Не поняла. А что там с финскими названиями? Мне это надо по жизни.

Comment: По некоторым источникам финские названия не склонятся.
Я этого не понимаю, хотя в живой речи наблюдал. Никаким правилам или разумным объяснениям это не поддается. Традиции такой точно не было. У бабушки (до семнадцатого года) была дача в месте, которое она произносила как Маалмалаамяя (финны, правда, говорили, что такое невозможно, фонетика искажена, самое близкое - Мalminmaa - Рудная Земля). Вполне себе склоняла.

Comment: Это про какие названия? Хельсинки не склоняется. Коломяги склоняются. Но оно давно обрусело. Мне кажется, тут нет единого правила.

Comment: Речь о названиях, оканчивающихся на -a, -я. Подробности могу обсудить в личке behamothus@mail.ru. Это всех касается, даже "доброжелателей", если разговор будет предметным.
Здесь я, скорее всего, доживаю последние дни. Увы...